# JavaFX 11 & Oracle JDK 11 on Eclipse - Error executing JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jar

I'm trying to run a JAR file from a JavaFX 11 project build using Eclipse 4.9 and Oracle JDK 11. Views were build using FXML (full project source code [here](https://github.com/acenelio/workshop-javafx-jdbc)).

*Note: I can build and run JARs from other non-JavaFX projects without any problems.*

**Procedure to build JAR file:**

1) Right click on project name -> Export -> Java/Runnable JAR file -> Next

2) Select Main class, select destination folder, choose third option for library handling

The result is a JAR file with a lib subfolder (I've added my db properties file manually):

[image]

The subfolder contains lib files from JavaFX 11 (and MySQL):

[image]

**Procedure I'm trying to run the app:**

If I try to run it using the command:

```
java -cp myapp.jar application.Main --module-path C:\appfolder\myapp_lib --add-modules=javafx.fxml,javafx.controls
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

However, I've heard that the module-path must come first, then if I try to run using the following command:

```
java --module-path C:\appfolder\myapp_lib --add-modules=javafx.fxml,javafx.controls -cp myapp.jar application.Main
```

I get this error:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        ... 5 more
```

As a final attempt, I tried some verbose options to get more information:

```
java -Djavafx.verbose=true -Dprism.verbose=true --module-path C:\appfolder\myapp_lib --add-modules=javafx.fxml,javafx.controls -cp myapp.jar application.Main
```

And then got a [huge error log (shared on Github)](https://github.com/acenelio/error-javafx-project/blob/master/error.txt).

How can I get my app running? Thanks.

Comment: JavaFX consists of both .jar files and native libraries.  You need to make sure the JavaFX native libraries are copied to the same location as the JavaFX .jar files.

Comment: @VGR what are those native libraries? Which files? I'm trying to google it but I'm not sure what to download.

Comment: They’re part of the JavaFX SDK.  They are in the same directory as the .jar files themselves.